# How to change color at "00" in UITextField Xcode

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

I'd like to change the color of "00" to gray and change the color of fix "555" to make black in my UITextField. How can i do ?
Thank you for your guidance.

```
var placeHolder = "00"

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if inputCoupon.text == self.placeHolder {
        inputCoupon.text = "00"
    }
}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if inputCoupon.text == "00" {
        textField.text = self.placeHolder
    }
}

@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let intTmp:Int = Int("\(textField.text ?? "00")") ?? 00
    sliderBarInputCoupon.setValue(Float(intTmp), animated:true)
    let setLabel:Int = Int(intTmp)
    let payCou = setLabel * 2
    let xCoupon = Double(payCou) * 0.15
    let reWard = Int(payCou) - Int(xCoupon)
    let calReward = String(reWard)
    rewardCoupon.text = "Reward :\(calReward)"
    rewardCoupon.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{
let currentText = textField.text ?? ""
guard let stringRange = Range(range, in: currentText) else{
    return false
}
let updateText = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: string)
    return updateText.count < 6
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDGQJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

`UITextField` has an `attributedText` property, that can be set to any `NSAttributedString` with any colors you like. For example:

```swift
// Create a string:
let attribString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "55500")

// Set the grey color to the last two characters (the black color is the default for the rest):
attribString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.gray, range: NSRange(location: 3, length: 2))

// Set the attributed string to your text field:
textField.attributedText = attribString
```

Here's the example from a Playground:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Create string extension for change text color

extension String

```
func attributedValue(_ value:String, _ color:UIColor) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
    attributedString.setColor(color: color, forText: value)
    return attributedString
}
```

2. Create NSMutableAttributedString Extension for find string range

extension NSMutableAttributedString

```
func setColor(color: UIColor, forText stringValue: String) {
   let range: NSRange = self.mutableString.range(of: stringValue, options: .caseInsensitive)
    self.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: color, range: range)
}
```

3. How to use this code ?

textfield.text = "5500"

textfield.text.attributedValue("00", UIColor.red)

**Above example will change the color of the "00" string**